# maximum Frequency in a list

Tags: python, list

This code does give the maximum frequency if only one number is repeated maximum times but lets suppose if 2 and 3 is repeated like  two two time each .. this code only produces 2 as an output but not 3 and if nothing is repeated it still gives the first element as the output.
What changes should I make so that if 'n' numbers are being repeated the same number of times it gives 'n' numbers as the output and if nothing is repeated it gives.. no number is being repeated as the output.Anyone?

```
def maxfrequency(arr,n):
    arr.sort()
    cur = 1
    max = 1
    res = arr[0]
    for i in range(1, n):
        if arr[i] == arr[i-1]:
            cur += 1
        else:
            if cur > max:
                max = cur
                res = arr[i-1]

            cur = 1

    if cur > max:
        max = cur
        res = arr[n-1]

    return res





n = int(input("Enter the size of the array: "))
arr = []
for i in range(0, n):
    ele = int(input())
    arr.append(ele)
s = maxfrequency(arr, n)
print("The most repeated element is",s)
```

Comment: Is this a practical problem or an educational exercise? This can be found easily with collections Counter

Comment: Educational exercise! from my schoool

Comment: res must be a list, so that it will save multiple elements, not only one. Also you must add an if statement, so that if max=1 it will return nothing

Comment: `from collections import Counter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I tried to change and only add on to the the implemented reasoning in the given code. Obviously, there are more Pythonic solutions and better than this code.

```
def maxfrequency(arr,n):
arr.sort()
cur = 1
max = 1
res = []
for i in range(1, n):
    if arr[i] == arr[i-1]:
        cur += 1
    else:
        if cur > max:
            max = cur
            res.clear()
            res.append(arr[i-1])
        elif cur == max and max != 1:
            max = cur
            res.append(arr[i-1])

        cur = 1

if cur > max:
    max = cur
    res.clear()
    res.append(arr[n-1])
elif cur == max and max != 1:
    max = cur
    res.append(arr[n-1])

return res
```

NOTE: rest of the code is the same.

As others have pointed out, you want to return a list in that case. Additionally, you would want to check when you see new integers while looping, then:

1. if you found a new max frequency at the i-th iteration, you just forget what you have seen before and stored as candidate(s) in your list and simply add the new integer candidate.
2. you also would need to check the case of multiple candidates having same max frequency (while considering the case of max frequency = 1).

I hope this helped.

Comment: Hey I have another question where i am in need to return an arraylist but it's just shwowing an error.. Ill be posting that like in 2 hours.. Can you help me with that.. I liked how you solved this code soo.. Anyways Thankyou for this one as well! Much appreciated

Comment: And And what does the clear function do??? Make the array empty?

Comment: list.clear(): Remove all items from the list. Equivalent to del a[:]. (from docs.python.org)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Counter` and `defaultdict` to get the result you want:

```py
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

def maxfrequency(arr):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for k,v in {k:v for (k,v) in Counter(arr).items() if v > 1}.items():
        d[v].append(k)
    keys = d.keys()
    if keys:
       return d[max(d.keys())]
    return []


myList = [1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5]

print(maxfrequency(myList))
```

Output:

```
[3, 4]
```

The code uses a `Counter` to count the frequency of the items and a `dict` comprehension to filter out frequencies of 1.

It then uses a `defaultdict` to collect up all the items by their frequency.

Finally if selects the items that have the maximum frequency, or returns an empty `list` (`[]`) if there was only one of each item anyway.